# Vertex Quality Matrix in PyMeshlab

Tags: python, pymeshlab

Using version 2021.10, is there a way to access the quality matrix values per vertex in PyMeshlab?

The quality values seem to be used for the color map which I can access using vertex_color_matrix for the current mesh but I can't find the values that were mapped.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean [vertex_scalar_array()](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/mesh.html#pmeshlab.Mesh.vertex_scalar_array) ?

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: Maybe you don't like the answer but Vertex_scalar_array() method returns the per vertex quality array of the mesh, which is the information that ABalrog needs.

Comment: I like your answer, now that you have phrased one, and your explanation. It should just be in the "Post Your Answer" post instead of the question which you currently have there. Please [edit] to move the explained answer from your comment into the answer itself and thereby avoid the impression of asking the clarification question whether OP sees any reason to not use this.